# mojo::mysql password with @

Tags: mysql, mojolicious

I am using Mojolicious with Mysql. Connecting to database is [simple](http://search.cpan.org/~harryl/Mojo-MySQL5-0.09/lib/Mojo/MySQL5/Connection.pm#SYNOPSIS):

```
url => Mojo::MySQL5->new(
  'mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/my_database')
```

Problem arises when the **@** sign is used in the password. Say the password is "one@here", the connection string will be like

```
url => Mojo::MySQL5->new(
  'mysql://user:one@here@127.0.0.1:3306/my_database')
```

The first @ will be misunderstood. I tried escaping (one\@here), with no luck.
Any idea? I cannot prevent users from choosing password with the "@".

Answer (score 2):

many hours later, I have found this solution, hope it would help someone with the same problem.

The **@** character must be encoded, in the password string, as **%40**. That's it.
So the code above will be:

```
url => Mojo::MySQL5->new('mysql://user:one%40here@127.0.0.1:3306/my_database')
```